# How to intercept and modify the response to a docker using owasp zap

Tags: owasp, zap

I have docker application running on my desktop and also OWASP zap also running on my desktop. how would i configure OWASP ZAP so that any request going out will be intercepted and response be modifyed before it goes to the docker app.

Answer (score 2):

Its more about how you configure your docker app than how you configure ZAP. ZAP listens on a host and port. You need to make sure that you can access that host:port from your docker container (you can just use curl to the host:port and see if that returns anything). Then you need to configure your app to proxy through ZAP. You might be able to do that within your app (if it supports proxies) or you might need to play around with the networking.